# A Web Part on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, web-config, gac

A slight variation on an old chestnut of a problem.
I have a SP2007 farm which we are upgrading to SP2010. We are carrying out UAT on our dev platform before conducting the full live environment migration.

I have a number of webparts  which are displaying the following error on the new platform:

> **Web Part Error:** A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type could not be found or it is not
>   registered as safe.

I have checked the web.config file and the SafeControl entries are inplace and set to Safe=True with the correct assembly info.
All the assemblies are present in the GAC
I have already tried retracting and redeploying the wsp files with no effect.

Is there anything else that can cause this error?